# Why do we use italics when recommending words?

Tags: discussion

Why do we *italicise* the term in reply to a suggestion asking for possible terms? I don't mean that we shouldn't, it looks cool, but what's the core reason? Why not **bold**?

Comment: Hmm. You're right. So, will this question be closed now? Or should I delete it? Sorry for not thoroughly searching...

Comment: You can delete it if you want, or else you can leave it and it will be closed as a duplicate, and if anyone ever searches for a similar question, they might find yours, which links to the answer.

Comment: Okay, It'll remain.

Comment: ...and happy to oblige. It's all to do with the *use-mention distinction* (as stated in an answer at that question).